# Python, numpy, printing in non scientific way

Tags: python, numpy, scientific-notation

ok so i've encountered some problem and i've tried several things but seems like nothing works...
so in general the problem is
i have ndarray matrix which has been set to dtype np.float64.
I'm filling up the matrix with some numbers (big numbers,some over 10^9)
set the print option to:

`np.set_printoptions(precision=1,linewidth=200,suppress=True)`

and then i print the matrix, what it prints is:

```
[[ -1.0e+01  -2.0e+09   0.0e+00   0.0e+00   0.0e+00   0.0e+00   0.0e+00]
 [ -6.0e+00  -2.0e+07   4.9e+08   0.0e+00   0.0e+00   0.0e+00   0.0e+00]
 [ -2.0e+00  -1.0e+03   5.0e+06  -6.1e+07   0.0e+00   0.0e+00   0.0e+00]
 [  2.0e+00   1.0e+03   5.1e+02  -6.3e+05   5.1e+06   0.0e+00   0.0e+00]
 [  6.0e+00   2.0e+07   5.0e+06   6.3e+05   1.0e+05  -3.1e+05   0.0e+00]
 [  1.0e+01   2.0e+09   4.9e+08   6.1e+07   5.1e+06   3.1e+05   3.1e+04]]
```

what i want to to print is:

```
[[ -1.0e+01  -2.0e+09   0         0         0         0         0      ]
 [ -6.0e+00  -2.0e+07   4.9e+08   0         0         0         0      ]
 [ -2.0e+00  -1.0e+03   5.0e+06  -6.1e+07   0         0         0      ]
 [  2.0e+00   1.0e+03   5.1e+02  -6.3e+05   5.1e+06   0         0      ]
 [  6.0e+00   2.0e+07   5.0e+06   6.3e+05   1.0e+05  -3.1e+05   0      ]
 [  1.0e+01   2.0e+09   4.9e+08   6.1e+07   5.1e+06   3.1e+05   3.1e+04]]
```

so as you can see I'm trying to convert all the 0.0e+00 (the scientific print)
into integer print (0), any ideas on how to do it ?

Comment: While perhaps understandable, it really doesn't make too much sense, nor does it really matter. For example, do you want to print `6.0e+00` as `6`, or as it is now? It's pretty much the same. Besdies, with `precision=1`, `0.0e+00` may very well be `0.01e+00` behind the scenes, which is not integer 0.

Comment: @Evert Well the number I usually get will be big and the precision 1 is just for the example (the precision will be 4-5 but I couldn't insert each row of the matrix  into 1 row here in the post) any way, I'm trying to covert only the zeroes to integer type

Comment: But you aren't converting types *at all* you are merely *changing the way the matrix is printed to the screen*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga well i understand that but supress parameter usally in
np.printoption usally prints it like the number is an integer (if it small enough)

Comment: I would simply not do it, unless you can show a good use case. Since I can only think of a case where the number 0 is special, consider create a masked array with numbers close or equal to zero masked out. That is clearer than printing things differently.

Comment: @Evert ok, i'll give some background about the matrix.
at start im creating matrix filled with zeroes and then im filling up the matrix with some big numbers, the filling is made in lower triangle
(im implementing Hermite interpolation polynom).
now the whole point of the print is to emphasize that it is a lower triangle matrix. so yeah, 0 is kind of special number here.